# Debugging successfully, but while running not giving desired output

Tags: java, debugging

I have a java code with me. When I am clicking on a 'Save' button (for which I have written an action), it is supposed to save the contents on the form, display message saying that the contents are saved and return to the main page. This is very straightforward.

What is happening is...it is neither displaying the message saying that the contents are saved nor returning to the main page. But, when I run the same piece of code with debugpoints enabled, it is giving the desired results.

Why this behavior could be?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you print out that part of code?

Answer (score 1):

It *could* be that you have some nondeterministic threading code which behaves itself when you slow things down for debugging. It *could* also be that the giant space hamster has settled in your JVM and is toying with you. With vague problem descriptions come vague interpretations.

Comment: Hey all, thaks for your replies. I know my problem description is vague, but it is because the code belongs to company and hence I cannot put it here on forum. When I have doubts, I try to be as specific as I can.

Comment: Try coming up with sample code that demonstrates your problem. Either you'll find the problem, or we'll have something more to go on.

Comment: By the way, now it is running fine. The one thing that was happening was, while running I was disabling all the debugpoints, except the one where user was putting value in the last field (that was focusLost event). It was stopping on that and hence not going to further debugpoints.